# Resize thickbox

Tags: thickbox

I try to create a WordPress TinyMCE plugin, that will use the Thickbox in order to display the popup dialog.

Now, I like to know if there is a way to resize the Thickbox, based on screen size, and not based on static values for width and height I can give on plugin development.

Any idea please ?

Comment: Questions on Thickbox and TinyMCE aren't on-topic questions for this site because they don't involve WordPress directly.  Migrating to Stack Overflow where you might get some better advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out the solution, and I place it here for the future use of another member.

I plug the following code into the TinyMCE plugin code:

```
ed.addCommand(
    'openPluginDialog', 
    function()
    {
        var w = window.innerWidth;        // Get the inner window width
        var h = window.innerHeight;       // Get the inner window height

        w = (w * 90) / 100;               // Calculate the dialog width
        h = (h * 85) / 100;               // Calculate the dialog height

        ed.windowManager.open(
            {
                file : url + '/plugin_dialog.html',
                width : w,                // The calculated window width
                height : h,               // The calculated window height
                inline : 1,
                title: 'Plugin dialog title'
            },
            {
                plugin_url : url
            }
        );
    }
);
```